# What are standard design rules for a Flex Printed Circuit (FPC)?

Tags: drc, flexible, fpc

For an FPC made out of Kapton (polyimide), what are the:

- min trace width
- min trace-trace separation
- min distance from a trace to the edge of the FPC
- min drill hole diameter
- min distance from a drill hole to the edge of the FPC
- min distance from a drill hole to a trace

I'm looking for the "lowest common denominator" that any competent fab should be able to handle. Thanks!

Comment: Ask yout PCB supplier!

Comment: That's different than asking for the standard. For example, if I was asking about non-flex PCB, the standard would be 4 4 rules. I don't believe it is right to downvote this, as the StackExchange policy on beginner questions is to allow them.

Comment: Just out of curiosity (since I have no idea what norms are followed in FPC layouts), aren't drill-holes preferably avoided with FPC? A drilling would reduce structural strength of an already flimsy substrate, I'd suspect.

Comment: Good question, @Anindo! Maybe mechanical drilling is bad but laser drilling is fine?

Comment: @EvolvedAI I'm not so sure - the material will still have its mechanical strength compromised for any non-trivial drill diameter. Possibly really tiny rivet style vias could work, with the rivet strengthening the drill-hole. One wouldn't be using through-hole parts on FPC anyway, right?

Comment: In my design at least, there's a necessary part that's only available in through-hole variety and must go on the FPC. If you are correct that this is impossible on raw Kapton, then I'll just put rigid-flex reinforcement sections where needed.

Comment: rigid-flex is the "standard" way to handle through-hole and large surface-mount components.

Comment: Thank you, @DrFriedParts. Since you know about FPCs, could you please provide an answer to the main question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no standard design rules, each manufacturer, unfortunately, has their own design rules.  These are dictated by how tightly controlled they run their processes.  Even if they use the same machines and processes it will vary a little.  Vias in FPC (which are small) are not an issue unless you expect to flex the cable lots and PTH parts should be fine as well as long the parts are mounted (the body supplies some rigidity).  SMT devices can be an issue as the rigid body combined with flexing generates large stresses on the pads and can pull the pads off.

Have run PTH, SMT and wire bonds onto FPC and rather than use rigid flex (which is a good option) we used FR-4 (and some times ceramic) stiffeners on the backside to prevent flexing in that region (no traces, just [image: fiberglass]).

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on Flex PCB's but a board house I've used in the past has the following specifications listed for flex boards and flex rigid boards material PI, PET, PEN, FR-4
:
**Minimum trace Width / Min Clearance:**
Inner: 0.5oz: 4/4mil, 1oz: 5/5mil,2oz: 5/7mil 
Outer: 1/3oz-0.5oz: 4/4mil, 1oz: 5/5mil, 2oz: 5/7mil

**Min Hole Ring**
Inner: 0.5oz: 4mil , 1oz: 5mil,2oz: 7mil 
Outer: 1/3oz-0.5oz: 4mil, 1oz: 5mil,2oz: 7mil

**Min Hole Size and Tolerance**
Min hole: 8mil
Tolerance: PTH±3mil, NPTH±2mil

**Minimum distance from a drill hole to the edge of the FPC** : Not listed ??

**Minimum  distance from a drill hole to a trace:** Apply Minimum trace Width / Min Clearance rule